# How can you create a Javascript safe string in Swift?

Tags: javascript, swift

When evaluating Javascript such as:

```
self.evaluateJavaScript("window.messenger.sendMessage('\(message)');
```

How can I make sure message is of a String type that I can pass safely into this method? I can imagine a quote or newline would already mess things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString()` to replace quotes, also create a extension for convenience:

```
extension String {
    var stringWithoutQuote: String {
        return self.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("'", withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\"", withString: "")
    }
}

self.evaluateJavaScript("window.messenger.sendMessage('\(message.stringWithoutQuote)');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Only escaping a quote wouldn't be enough to be a safe string for Javascript right? A newline in the string would also break it and perhaps I am missing more characters that would break it.

Comment: Not sure if another characters would break the rules of safe string for JS, you can trim the white spaces or newlines by using this method: `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())`

Comment: Is there anyway I can check the result? If I print it, the changes aren't show, I figure print processes the characters like newline \n

Answer (score 3):

```
extension String {
    var javaScriptString: String {
        var safeString  = self as NSString

        safeString      = safeString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\", withString: "\\\\")
        safeString      = safeString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\"", withString: "\\\"")
        safeString      = safeString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\'", withString: "\\\'")
        safeString      = safeString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withString: "\\n")
        safeString      = safeString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\r", withString: "\\r")
        safeString      = safeString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\t", withString: "\\t")

        safeString      = safeString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\u{0085}", withString: "\\u{0085}")
        safeString      = safeString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\u{2028}", withString: "\\u{2028}")
        safeString      = safeString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\u{2029}", withString: "\\u{2029}")

        return safeString as String
    }
}
```